# npm start throwing Sass Dart Error "Bad state: Can't access parent outside of a module" in Create React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

My team recently have been running into an odd error when trying to `npm start` a Create React App we are developing. The error is `Bad state: Can't access __parent outside of a module` which is causing the Build to fail. We have used this setup for about a year without having this issue. The node-sass version we are using is `"node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.32.5"` It is a dart Sass implementation. We have tried reinstall node modules and clearing npm cache to no avail. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. The full error message is below.

```
C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:27130
      throw error;
      ^

 

Bad state: Can't access __parent outside of a module.
    at Object.wrapException (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:1235:17)
    at _EvaluateVisitor2._async_evaluate0$_assertInModule$1$2 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:63998:15)
    at _EvaluateVisitor2._async_evaluate0$_assertInModule$2 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:64001:19)
    at C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:67128:27
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:4360:15)        
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:25617:12)
    at Object._asyncStartSync (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:4324:20)
    at _EvaluateVisitor2.visitCssDeclaration$body$_EvaluateVisitor0 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:67133:16)
    at _EvaluateVisitor2.visitCssDeclaration$1 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:67114:19)
    at ModifiableCssDeclaration0.accept$1$1 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:73021:22) {
  dartException: StateError {
    message: "Can't access __parent outside of a module.",
    '$thrownJsError': Bad state: Can't access __parent outside of a module.
        at Object.wrapException (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:1235:17)
        at _EvaluateVisitor2._async_evaluate0$_assertInModule$1$2 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:63998:15)
        at _EvaluateVisitor2._async_evaluate0$_assertInModule$2 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:64001:19)
        at C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:67128:27
        at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:4360:15)    
        at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:25617:12)       
        at Object._asyncStartSync (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:4324:20)
        at _EvaluateVisitor2.visitCssDeclaration$body$_EvaluateVisitor0 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:67133:16)
        at _EvaluateVisitor2.visitCssDeclaration$1 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:67114:19)      
        at ModifiableCssDeclaration0.accept$1$1 (C:\Git Projects\CustomerHierarchy\client-app\node_modules\node-sass\sass.dart.js:73021:22) {       
      dartException: [Circular],
      '$cachedTrace': [_StackTrace]
    }
  }
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! optimiz-react-template@1.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the optimiz-react-template@1.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JonnakutiMB\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-27T13_24_05_783Z-debug.log
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "optimiz-react-template",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/prismjs": "^1.16.1",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.3",
    "@types/react-autosuggest": "^9.3.14",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^2.11.0",
    "@types/react-day-picker": "^5.3.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-stickynode": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/smooth-scrollbar": "^8.2.5",
    "@types/uniqid": "^5.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "dom-helpers": "^3.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.14.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.6",
    "latest": "^0.2.0",
    "local-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "merge": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.32.11",
    "npm": "^6.14.7",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "prismjs": "^1.20.0",
    "protrans-react-ui": "^2.14.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
    "react-context-devtool": "^2.0.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.14.0",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.4.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-paginate": "^6.3.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-treble": "^2.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-spinners-kit": "^1.9.1",
    "react-stickynode": "^3.0.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.5.3",
    "treble-fetch": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "treble-gsm": "^3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.7",
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "lint-staged": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "update-PTRUI": "npm install protrans-react-ui@latest"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we recently figured out the issue. A stylesheet was referenced in the app from a node module. The node module was updated and the path to the stylesheet did not exist anymore. For some reason the linter only had an issue with it when a production build was being created. The error message was very vague. We use Create React App and its configurations for building a production app.